# Draw vertical line on top of horizontal table lines

Tags: tables, tabularx

I'm using two `\hline` for horizontal line and  `\begin{tabular}{c | c c c c c}` option for vertical line. This is some part of my table:

[image]

I want vertical line on *top* of double horizontal lines. How can I do that?

Comment: What you want is not clear to me. Could you post a minimal (non)working example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know there is a package that can do this (which I cannot recall), but here it is hardwired as `\dhline`, which must be defined based on the point size of the document (since I don't know the macros that define the rule thicknesses and vertical skips inside `tabular`)

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
%\def\dhline{\\[-10.2pt]\hline\\[-14.2pt]\hline\\[-10.pt]}% for 10pt
\def\dhline{\\[-11.6pt]\hline\\[-16.0pt]\hline\\[-11.6pt]}% for 11pt
%\def\dhline{\\[-12.5pt]\hline\\[-16.8pt]\hline\\[-12.6pt]}% for 12pt
\begin{document}
\tabcolsep=2pt
hline:
\begin{tabular}{c|c}
\hline
&\\
\hline
\hline
&\\
\hline
\hline
&\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
dhline:
\begin{tabular}{c|c}
\hline
&\\
\dhline
&\\
\dhline
&\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And here is an example showing actual content in such tabulars:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use `hhline`

```
\documentclass[margin=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{hhline}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{c | c }
   & \\ \hline
   & \\ \hhline{=|=}
   & \\ \hhline{=|=}
   & \\ \hhline{=|=}
   & \\ \hhline{=|=}
   & \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Response to the comment.

It is only the viewer artefact. Zoom in and things will be clear. There are no segments of line.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for answer. There is a problem in this structure. When we use something like this : `\hhline{=|=====}`, There are segments of lines. You can see this in above picture.

Comment: @user2991243 There are no segments of lines. Zoom in and you will see. It is only a pdf viewer issue. See the edit.

Answer (score 1):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`, the vertical rules cross the `\hline\hline`.

```
\documentclass[margin=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{NiceTabular}{c|c}
 & \\ \hline
 & \\ \hline\hline
 & \\ \hline\hline
 & \\ \hline\hline
 & \\ \hline\hline
 & \\ \hline
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]